# WebAuthenticationBroker in WinJS not accepting token longer than 2k length

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs

We are trying to use WebAuthenticationBroker in a WinJS app using ACS as the provider.

The problem is our SWT token is a little large, it seems longer than 2K and therefore exceeds max length for a URI.
Can anyone tell me is there a way to return large tokens to WebAuthenticationBroker ?

Answer (score 0):

Since the max length of a URI is 2048 characters, you will need to find a way to reduce the URL to the point that the tokens can fit in the 2048 characters.